# Container not resolving a single Interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor

I have a common site Controller that all my controllers derive from for my MVC website.  I have placed the common Service classes to all View/Controllers in there.

```
public class SiteController : Controller {
        #region Properties
        public IGlobalService GlobalService { get; set; }
        public IMenuService MenuService { get; set; }
        public IClientService ClientService { get; set; }
        public ICertificateService CertificateService { get; set; }
        #endregion

        protected override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext filterContext ) {
            ViewBag.ErrorEmail = GlobalService.ErrorEmail;
            ViewBag.Company = GlobalService.Company;
            ViewBag.TopLevel = MenuService.GetTopLevel();

            base.OnActionExecuting( filterContext );
        }
```

Recently, I started implementing a dynamic Menu, and implemented a ChildActionOnly method for the Menu partial

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Menu() {
    var items = MenuService.GetTopLevel();
    if( items == null || items.Count > 0 )
        throw new NullReferenceException("Menu must have at least 1 top-level Menu Item!");

    var topmenu = new Menu();
    foreach( var item in items ) {
        topmenu.Items.Add( new MenuItem( item.MenuId ){
            MenuItemName = item.Key,
            MenuItemPath = item.Value
        });
    }

    return PartialView("_Menu", topmenu);
}
```

Up until the point that I implemented the ChildActionOnly method, theoretically the MenuService object was being injected.  I cannot verify this as it wasn't being used until I started debugging it `ViewBag.TopLevel = MenuService.GetTopLevel();`.

That being said, when I put the break point on the line with `ViewBag.TopLevel` I can inspect 3 of the 4 Service properties associated with the Controller.  As stated, the `MenuService` property is the only one that is not getting initialized.

Here is my `WindsorContainer` initializer:

```
public static void Initialize(string log4netPath) {
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Kernel.ComponentModelCreated += ( s => {
        if( s.LifestyleType == LifestyleType.Undefined )
            s.LifestyleType = LifestyleType.PerWebRequest;
    } );

    container.Install(
        new DomainInstaller(),
        new RepositoryInstaller() ,
        new ServiceInstaller() ,
        FromAssembly.This()
    );
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new WindsorControllerFactory( container.Kernel ) );

    container.AddFacility( new LoggingFacility( LoggerImplementation.Log4net , log4netPath ) );

    CWC.Init( container );
}
```

`ServiceInstaller` declaration:

```
public class ServiceInstaller : IWindsorInstaller {
    #region IWindsorInstaller Members

    public void Install( Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer container , Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration.IConfigurationStore store ) {
        container.Register( Types.FromAssembly( Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() )
            .Where( t => t.Namespace.StartsWith( "Woodsoft.Service" ) )
            .WithService.FirstInterface().LifestylePerWebRequest() );
    }

    #endregion
}
```

`MenuService` declaration:

```
public interface IMenuService {
    ICollection<Menu> GetTopLevel();
    ICollection<Menu> GetChildren( int id );
}
public class MenuService : IMenuService {
    public IMenuRepository MenuRepository { get; set; }

    public MenuService() { }

    public ICollection<Menu> GetTopLevel() {
        return MenuRepository.FindAll()
            .Where( m => ( m.ParentId == null || m.ParentId == 0 ) )
            .ToList();
    }

    public ICollection<Menu> GetChildren( int id ) {
        return MenuRepository.FindChildren( id );
    }
}
```

Maybe there is something I am missing, but if 3 of the 4 Service objects are initializing and accessible when debugging, what is going on that would cause 1 of the Service objects to not initialize and, by proxy, not be useable.

For comparison here is the `GlobalService` object:

```
public interface IGlobalService {
    string this[ string key ] { get; set; }
    string AdminEmail { get; set; }
    string BCCEmail { get; set; }
    string ErrorEmail { get; set; }
    string Domain { get; set; }
    string Company { get; set; }
}

public class GlobalService : IGlobalService {
    public IGlobalRepository GlobalRepository { get; set; }

    public GlobalService() { }

    #region Getter/Setter methods
    public string GetValue( string key ) {
        return GlobalRepository.FindByKey( key ).Value;
    }
    private void SetValue( string key , string value ) {
        var global = GlobalRepository.FindByKey( key );
        global.Value = value;
        GlobalRepository.Save();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IGlobalService Members

    public string this[ string key ] {
        get { return GetValue( key ); }
        set { SetValue( key , value ); }
    }

    public string AdminEmail {
        get { return this[ "admin_email" ].ToEmail( Domain ); }
        set { this[ "admin_email" ] = value; }
    }

    public string BCCEmail {
        get { return this[ "bcc_email" ].ToEmail( Domain ); }
        set { this[ "bcc_email" ] = value; }
    }

    public string ErrorEmail {
        get { return this[ "error_email" ].ToEmail( Domain ); }
        set { this[ "error_email" ] = value; }
    }

    public string Domain {
        get { return this[ "domain" ]; }
        set { this[ "domain" ] = value; }
    }

    public string Company {
        get { return this[ "company" ]; }
        set { this[ "company" ] = value; }
    }
    #endregion


}
```

### Update: 2013-11-22 @ 10:59

I changed it from `IMenuService` to `IMenuRepository` and it loaded the Interface just fine.

Though there was an underlying issue with some of property/methods inside `MenuService` but it doesn't seem there is.

### Update 2013-11-25

Here is the `WindsorControllerFactory`:

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory {
    private readonly IKernel Kernel;

    public WindsorControllerFactory( IKernel kernel ) {
        Kernel = kernel;
    }

    public override void ReleaseController( IController controller ) {
        Kernel.ReleaseComponent( controller );
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance( System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext , Type controllerType ) {
        if( controllerType == null ) 
            throw new HttpException( 404 , string.Format( "The controller for path '{0}' could not be found." , requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path ) );

        return ( IController ) Kernel.Resolve( controllerType );
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that mean you solved your problem? In that case, you should post the solution as an answer to the question and then accept it.

Comment: Nope, the problem is that its not Resolve'ing the `MenuService` object but it is Resolve'ing the other 3 objects in that namespace.

Comment: So if I manually Resolve the Interface needed, it loads it into the Property.  How do I get the Windsor Container to "Inject" Resolve dependencies into a Classes Property(s)?  In previous web-apps I have supported they used a dummy Attribute to identify injection but that was for Windsor 1.x.  I am using Windsor 3.2.  Would rather have it skim through classes and Resolve when necessary.

Comment: Can you post the code for your WindsorControllerFactory?  Since that is (most likely) the code that handles dependency injection, seeing it might help us out.

Comment: @PatrickSteele Added the Factory as requested.